# How to exclude NA values from a percentage calculation with summarize function

Tags: r, group-by, na, percentage, summarize

I'm a begninner in R  and I want to calculate the percentage of values from my dataframe (ileagedata). Here is what I used:

```
ileagedata %>% 
  group_by( Age_t0 ) %>%
  summarise (percent = 100 * n() / nrow( ileagedata ))
```

And here is my result:

```
Age_t1     percent
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 adult        33.0 
2 juvenile     28.5 
3 juvenile<1    1.81
4 NA           36.6
```

I would like to not take NA values in consideration for the percentage. I tried several things as na.rm, na.omit but I cannot make it work. I do not know where to place it in the formula.

Could someone help me by saying on how to do it please?
Thank you

Comment: How about you filter out NA before hand?

Comment: I tried, the problem is that it deleted the complete row from the dataframe, deleting other data that I need. I used this formula:

ileagedata <- subset(ileagedata, ileagedata$Age_t1!="?")

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
ileagedata %>%
group_by( Age_t0 ) %>%
summarise (percent = if(!is.na(Age_t0)){100 * n() / nrow( ileagedata %>% filter(!is.na(ileagedata$Age_t0)))}else{NA})
```